# createrepo does not delete .repodata file automatically

Tags: sqlite, ibm-cloud, redhat, yum, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

**Command**

```
createrepo .
```

**Output** 
    (process:2560): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_timer_stop: assertion 'timer != NULL' failed

```
(process:2560): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_timer_destroy: assertion 'timer != NULL' failed
Could not remove  temp metadata dir: .repodata
Error was [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/app/run/local_repo/application/test/./.repodata'
Please clean up this directory manually.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 309, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 274, in main
mdgen.doRepoMetadata()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/createrepo/__init__.py", line 1014, in doRepoMetadata
gen_func(complete_path, csum)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlitecachec.py", line 61, in getOtherdata
self.repoid))
TypeError: Can not create db_info table: disk I/O error
```

We have tried Following command to clean cache:

yum clean all

Comment: "Disk I/O error" typically indicates disk full, or no write access, or an actual hardware error.

Comment: if we clear the cache, then createrepo works for first time. then throws the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue was due to disk error of the Virtual Machine.
The Disk had got corrupted.